# Formatting values returned from toString

Tags: groovy

Kind of a groovy newbie so bear with me. I have a form that has a series of text fields. I’m filtering out two of those fields as well. This part works but the format for the values that gets returned isn’t how I would like it to be formatted. Should I be using toString or join or something else? I’m a groovy newbie so code samples would be much appreciated

**Here’s my code:**

```
String message = request.requestParameterMap.findAll { key, value ->!(key in [“userKey", "topicKey"]) }.toString()
```

**Here’s my output:**

```
[fname:[joey], lname:[bats], phone:[999-999-9999], email:[test@gmail.com]]
```

**Here’s ideally how I’d like my output:**

```
fname: joey
lname: bats
phone: 999-999-9999
email: test@gmail.com
```

Comment: `message = message.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""); message = message.replaceAll(",\\s+", "\n");`

Comment: Thanks @AntonH is there a way to do it calling replaceAll only once though? Seems redundant but maybe it's necessary.

Comment: I don't see a way to replace it with just one `replaceAll`, since you're not replacing with the same text, but there may be a way, or just using another technique. I went for quick and dirty, but functional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message = 
    request.requestParameterMap
           .findAll { key, value ->!(key in [“userKey", "topicKey"]) }
           .collect { k, v -> "$k: ${v[0]}\n" }
           .join()
```

should give the message in expected format

```
fname: joey
lname: bats
phone: 999-999-9999
email: test@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro worked perfect! Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be to use a series of `replaceAll(...)`s to format the code like you want it.

To replace the leading and trailing brackets:

```
message = message.replaceAll("^[|]$", "");
```

To replace opening brackets with a space:

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\[", " ");
```

And to replace closing brackets comma space with newline:

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\],\\s+", "\n");
```

It's very possible, even likely, that there exists some tool to format it quicker, but none that come to my mind.

Depending on what you want to do, you may prefer to `split` the string to get an array, but it really depends on what you're going to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inject` to reduce the map to a string:

```
​def m = [​fname: 'joey', name: 'bats', phone: 999-999-9999, email: 'test@gmail.com']

m.inject("") { result, e ->
   result += "$e.key: $e.value\n"
   result
}
```

Results in:

```
fname: joey
name: bats
phone: -9999
email: test@gmail.com
```